# Wordpress add_filter before posts

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook

i have looked all day for an answer to this i have an assignment brief that requires me too add a guess the logo script to any home page of a Wordpress installation.

i understand how to use add_action do_action and add_filter, at the moment i am calling my function via the add_filter to the content. This works however it adds the script to every post. I need a filter / action to run my function after or before the posts e.g

```
My function
[post1]
[post2]
[post3]
```

at the moment it is displaying like so

```
[post1 | my function | post content]
[post2 | my function | post content]
[post3 | my function | post content]
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the loop_start and loop_end hooks. See the example below.

```
function myFunction() {
    //do something
}
add_action('loop_start', 'myFunction'); //Call your function before the loop
add_action('loop_end', 'myFunction');  //Call your function after the loop
```

You can also check for the home page using is_home() function inside myFunction().

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah thats awesome just need to work out how to stop it displaying on ever iteration of the Wordpress loop as it adds it to the navigation as well as the main content

Comment: @andrewhutchings You can check the post type inside myFunction() and if its 'post' then display your logic.

Comment: post type does not work as apparently both a post. thanks so much for your help so far!!.